# Concurrency in java threads

Tags: java, concurrency

Two threads(t1 and t2) are running. t1 calls join on t2 .Suppose t2 dies due to some exception then what will be the behavior of the waiting thread t1 i.e, will thread t1 will remain in blocked state indefinitely or will resume back to runnable state after some time ...Not clear about the behavior and more specifically the rationale behind that.

Comment: You can easily try this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the about page at http://stackoverflow.com/about - there you can read some simple rules about asking questions; one of them is: "Don't ask questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)". So, in the future, please first try to find the answer yourself (e.g. trying out and reading the API docs). Then create the question and tell us, what you did (e.g., reading and trying) and why it did not solve your problem/question (e.g., docs were not understandable, test did behave as expected).

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc has to say for [Thread.join(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29):

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`. As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked.

And this is the description for [Thread.isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29):

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

You can assume that the implementation of Thread is protected against exceptions occurring inside the `run()` method. So in any case, when the run method terminates (no matter if normally or because of an exception), other threads waiting on `join()` can continue.

As for the rationale: This is, of course, so that your program does not get caught in an endless waiting state.

Answer (score 0):

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29):

> Waits for this thread to die.

So, when the thread dies, `join()` returns.